# What is {baseUri}/echo/resource API?

Tags: azure-application-insights, asp.net-apicontroller

We got a lot of failed requests throwing from Get /echo/resource in the Azure application insights, I could not find it in our .net projects (for the rest failed APIs I can find them in the code), also When I launch the project in the browser, with using the developer tool, this echo API is not in API lists under Network tab. Below are the screen shots captured from the application insights:
[APIs error list sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy2Dz.jpg)
[transaction detail of echo/resource error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW8VR.jpg)

I googled and get the basic info about what is echo, but not quite sure if we are not using it in the .net project, where it comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the path of URL, it seems to be coming from the [API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts) placed before your REST API application. APIM [has the default Echo API for testing purposes](https://azure.github.io/apim-lab/apim-lab/1-apimCreation/#verifying-the-api-management-instance). This API seems to have been configured/exposed or is being used to route the request to the backend App itself.